# Nodejs:callback function error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Console output: `undefined`

I want to inherit from the previous function. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```js
var rs;

function selectAllFromKullanici(callback) {       
  Kullanici.find(function (err,results) {
    rs = results;
    callback(rs);
  });
};

module.exports.usersGET = function(req,res,rs) {
  console.log(rs);
}
```

Comment: What? Your code doenst make sense.

Comment: you haven't even called selectAllFromKullanici()

Comment: Are you calling the method `selectAllFromKullanici` in your code?? If you don't call it, it will not modify the value of `rs` and will show you the value that is set in `rs` on line 1 which is `undefined`

Comment: How do I send the variable from the first function to the second function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your function and handle the callback.

```
module.exports.usersGET = function(req,res) {
    selectAllFromKullanici((result) => { 
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

Though it's important to note that you're breaking the error first callback convention and you're not handling the possible database error in the find callback.

Comment: You are a genius :)  
ty.